# Reference for analyticity of $K$-theory

Tags: homotopy-theory, kt.k-theory-and-homology

This is a follow-up to my last question, [Homotopy excision for structured ring spectra -- reference?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/177058/homotopy-excision-for-structured-ring-spectra-reference). The immediate reason why I care about Blakers-Massey theorems for ring spectra is to prove that algebraic $K$-theory for such rings is what is called an analytic functor. Has someone done this already?